# Is it possible to export interfaces / types encapsulated within a namespace / module, in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm relatively new to Typescript and am attempting to import and re-use interfaces from a private ts repo created to share types / classes / interfaces between node/ts server and Angular client. This is achieved by requiring the private repo as a dependency in the Angular package.json.

The namespaces are declared within the ts repo like so:

```
export namespace foo {
  export interface Bar {
   ...
  };
  export type Foo {
  ...
  };
```

I can access functions and classes (e.g. foo.fn()) after importing foo to the client `import { foo } from 'repo/foo`, but I'm unable to see or access the Bar interface or Foo type.

Is this because interfaces and types are ts only and the Angular client can only import things which are compile-able to javascript?

The package owner wants to declare everything in namespaces but I don't want to re-declare / duplicate types and interfaces, as this would negate most of the purpose of the shared ts package.

If you could advise alternative approaches that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

** SOLVED **

I solved this issue on my own through trial and error. What worked in my use case (sharing a separate TS repo, across separate and independent client / server TS repos (NON-monorepo)) was by declaring namespaces exactly like I have in my original question, but the problems were:

1) vscode intellisense does not reliably update on every `npm i` of the shared package. Sometimes it does. Sometimes it doesn't. Always close and re-open the **entire vscode window** (where you ran npm i to import) if it does not recognise changes to your namespaces / types / enums of the shared repo. You don't have to close ALL windows; just the one that has not updated. Over time you will learn exactly what you can and can't import and when intellisense has not updated properly. Some times navigating to the namespace in the compiled /node_modules/ will cause the changes to be recognised, but not always.

2) I was trying to link to the shared repo locally on my own machine in the package.json. When you install a ts remote, it compiles; you can only import and use what's compiled by ts to `.d.ts` suffixed files. I found it easier to make my changes in the shared repo, commit and push them to remote, then run `npm i git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>#<branch>` in the client / server repos. This ensured I always have the same experience as other devs installing the shared package from remote.

3) you must `export` both the namespace and EVERY encapsulated interface / type / enum within that namespace, otherwise it won't compile to `.d.ts` and you can't import those changes to a separate location from remote.

4) ALWAYS commit the package-lock.json with client / server commits (for changes made to the shared package), as it keeps the exact shared package commit hash that has been imported for those changes.

I also created a single file and namespace for ALL enums and types (enums.ts, with each enum alphabetically ordered within the namespace). This was much cleaner and easier to share than allowing them to be declared anywhere, especially for importing into client / server:

```js
import { enums, types } from 'shared_package';

const variable: types.ProductType = enums.PRODUCT.TYPE
```

Try to prevent namespace clashes with common variable names, perhaps by differentiating every namespace e.g. `ns_enums`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In typescript interfaces used just in compilation step for check the correct usage of reference variables. Typescript compiler don't create function of **interface** or **type** in javascript.
Your shoold use intefaces and types just to define type of variables and functions:

```
import { foo } from 'repo/foo';

var item1: foo.Bar;
var func = (): foo.Foo => {
...
}
```

[Typescript interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) 
[Typescript namespaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing)

If you use compiled to javascript lib 'repo', you can't use types and interfaces, that been declared in typescript, because compiler don't create any things for interface in js.
But you can use not compiled lib by import this one as module if backend and client part in one project.

Comment: You can actually share namespaces, interfaces, types and enums from compiled packages. See my ** SOLVED ** answer above! Thanks.